¿Por qué parte del mensaje automático de cierre aparece en inglés?
Al votar una pregunta para el cierre, casi la totalidad del mensaje automático aparece en inglés, como se puede ver en la captura:

¿Hay un bug en el sistema?

Faltaba la traducción en traducir.

Esta pregunta es similar a: ¿Por qué aparece  en inglés? ¿Estamos perdiendo traducciones?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. || ¿Cómo se llama esto? ¿Inception?
